# Finding all consecutive indices that sum X number on list

Tags: python

I'm currently practicing some Python and came across this problem. Let's say we have a list of integers and we want to find out all the indices of its elements that sum a certain number (in particular, the first index and the last index). Here's an example:

```
arr = [6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2]
sum_to_find = 13
```

So we have the array, and we want to find all elements that sum 13, and save the indexes (first and last of the interval) each time. The answer for this problem would be:

```
answer = [[0, 1], [2, 5], [3, 7], [9, 10], [12, 19], [13, 19], [14, 19], [18, 22]]
```

Below is the code I've tried:

```
def find_sum_range(array):
    summ = 0
    lst_sum = []
    lst_ix = []

    i = 0
    j = -1
    while i < len(array):
        if summ < 13:
            val = array[i]
            summ += val
            lst_ix.append(i)
        elif summ == 13:
            lst_sum.append(lst_ix)
            j += 1
            i = lst_sum[j][1]
            summ = 0
            lst_ix = []
        i += 1

    return lst_sum
```

But it's only returning the first two answers, mostly because I can't seem to properly backtrack the i iterator to start again from the first index of the last sum it correctly identified.

Comment: how about [0, 10]?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you're trying to do; don't expect us to reverse-engineer your intent from uncommented code and meaningless variable names.  Among other things, backtracking an iterator is a *bad* programming practice; I hope that's not an accurate description of your intent.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is unnecessarily complicated. Utilizing list slicing produces much simpler code. Try this:

```
def find_sum_range(array):
    result = []
    for begin in range(len(array)):
        for end in range(begin, len(array)):
            if sum(array[begin:end+1]) == 13:
                result.append([begin,end])
    return result
```

or, with list comprehension:

```
def find_sum_range(array):
    return [ [begin,end]
             for begin in range(len(array))
             for end in range(begin+1, len(array))
             if sum(array[begin:end+1]) == 13 ]
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thanks a lot! Don't know why i didn't think of list slicing.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you use `i = lst_sum[j][1]` to try to backtrack. This is the second element in the list you just saved. You should use `i = lst_sum[j][0]` instead.

Also, you need to treat the case where you go above 13.

You can reduce the number of operations needed by moving a start index instead of keeping all the potential list indexes and deleting everything each time you arrive at 13 or above:

```
def find_sum_range(array):
    summ = 0
    lst_sum = []
    start = 0
    end = -1
    for element in array:
        summ += element
        end += 1
        while summ >= 13:
            if summ == 13:
                lst_sum.append([start, end])
            summ -= array[start]
            start += 1
    return lst_sum
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to this problem would be to use nested loops. So, go over each element in the list and for each of them iterate over the elements in the list that come after that element.

As soon as the sum exceeds or is equal to summ, we can break the nested for loop and go over to the main loop. If it turns out to be equal, then just append a list with the correct indices to the answer.

```
arr = [6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2]
req_sum = 13

answer = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
  curr_s = arr[i]

  for k in range(i+1, len(arr)):
    curr_s += arr[k]
    if curr_s >= req_sum:
      if curr_s == req_sum:
        answer.append([i, k])
      break

print(answer)
```